# SQL Query Replace All

Tags: sql, database

I want to modify the following query:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content =
      REPLACE(post_content, 'http://oldlink.com', 'http://newlink.com');
```

To be something that goes through all tables, columns and values. Something similar to this (but this doesn't work):

```
UPDATE * SET *= REPLACE(*, 'http://oldlink.com', 'http://newlink.com');
```

I want to replace every instance of my old link to my new link in my database.  Is there any way to do this?

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I forgot to mention, it's MySQL.  I'm currently going through all the answers and I'll be back and let you know what worked.  Thanks everyone!

**UPDATE 2**

Hi guys (and girls), I decided to just dump the database and do manual search and replace (with TextWrangler).  As this isn't (currently) a large DB, it's probably the easiest way.

Comment: What RDBMS please?

Comment: The easiest way is to dump your DB into flat file, replace in it and then import back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one that works on SQL Server -- does something like this work for you?

[Search and Replace SQL Server data in all columns, of all tables](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/sql_server_search_and_replace.htm)

> Here's a stored procedure named, SearchAndReplace, that searches
>   through all the character columns of all tables in the current
>   database, and replaces the given string with another user provided
>   string.

Comment: +1, although I was looking forward to writing some epic dynamic SQL myself :)

Answer (score 1):

This mssql script will whine a bit if there is a computed column in a table, but it will still execute:

```
DECLARE @searchvalue varchar(100)
DECLARE @newvalue varchar(100)
SET nocount off

SET @searchvalue = 'http://oldlink.com'
SET @newvalue = 'http://newlink.com'

SELECT * into #t FROM 
(
SELECT 'update [' + a.TABLE_name + '] SET ['+ column_name+ ']=''' + @newvalue + '''
where [' +a.column_name+
']='''+@searchvalue +'''' sqlstring
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a
join 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES b
ON a.TABLE_name = b.TABLE_name
and b.TABLE_type = 'base table'
WHERE data_type in ('varchar', 'char', 'nvarchar')
and character_maximum_length >= len(@newvalue)
) a

DECLARE @sqlstring as nvarchar(500)
DECLARE SqlCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT sqlstring FROM #t
OPEN SqlCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM SqlCursor
INTO @sqlstring
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

     EXEC(@sqlstring)
     FETCH NEXT FROM SqlCursor
     INTO @sqlstring
END
CLOSE SqlCursor
DEALLOCATE SqlCursor
DROP TABLE #t
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the database. I currently use Sybase ASA, where you cannot do this literally but it can be done by checking the column names from a join of `systable` and `syscolumn` and then using `execute immediate`